# Some way how "to prevent" user to modify url

Tags: php

In one page are multiple rows of records (information).

User can click link at the end of each row. Opens new page (popup) like `host/pageaddress.php?id=777` `777` is id of mysql row. In the new page I display information that is recorded in mysql with id 777.

If user wants, he can change 777 to any other number and gets displayed corresponding mysql row. Modifying id in such way user can access only table and rows which the user is allowed to access. And at the moment I do not know any security hole because of such modification (if someone knows, please, write).

But I do not like to allow user such modifications (feeling uncomfortable). When searched I found information, that I can not prevent user to modify. However know one website, where I can not modify url
[image]

Tried to write something in address bar and i can not. I do not know why (maybe because of https?)

So at the moment think of following solution.

At main page create `$_SESSION['display'] = 'something';`

In new popup page

```
if(isset($_SESSION['display'])){
echo ' content';
}
```

Then at the bottom of page `unset($_SESSION['display']);`

So if user modify url, page reloads and there is `$_SESSION['display']` is not set. So no content.

Please, advice if such solution is ok? Some better solution?

**Update**
The above mentioned solution appears useless. But if to think regarding solution, here one another:

1) At main page create hash, and name for example `$hash`

2) `$_SESSION['display'] = $hash;`

3) record `$hash` in mysql

4) in new popup window (file) check if `$_SESSION['display']' exists and is equal to hash in mysql. At the end of page unset hash and delete from mysql

This is just to think about possible solution... does it work?

Comment: Nothing can stop you, even in that website. I can just open another window and go to https://www2.vid.gov.lv/eds/Print/9898, or any other number. Voila, changed address.

Comment: I just tried. At first click on link. Opens page with url http://localhost/pageaddress.php?id=777. Then I changed url to http://localhost/pageaddress.php?id=774 and see nothing. Because $_SESSION['display'] does not exists

Comment: That doesn't work. Just reload the main page before going to the other number.

Comment: Yes, you are true. Reloaded and see all content. Ok seems must leave as it is (without any sessions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If user wants, he can change 777 to any other number

Yes. There is absolutely no way to control what the user instructs their browser to ask your server for.

> and gets displayed corresponding mysql row.

If you only want some rows to be available to the user, then authenticate that user and check if they are authorised to view that row.

For example, some pesudo-code:

```
if user is not logged in
    provide login page
else
    if user id matches row's owner id field
        provide data
    else
        provide error message
```

> However know one website, where I can not modify url

That's what happens when you open a popup window and tell it not to show the toolbar. It doesn't provide any security because the user can still copy the URL into a new window and modify it as much as they like.

> So if user modify url, page reloads and there is $_SESSION['display'] is not set

That just means they have to copy the URL into a new window between the time they visit the main page and the time they click on whatever triggers the popup.

It's annoying and twiddly, but not secure.

Comment: Yes. Copied popup window url. Opened new tab, modified url and all works.